# When importing start_settings in terminal, get an error about installing pylast

Tags: pylast

I downloaded a project from Github and am trying to run it. In the readme file, there are instructions, including the following:

Create new database in bash

```
&& python
>> from smart_settings import db
>> db.create_all()
```

I wanted to double check that the db object exists in smart_settings so in terminal I cd into the project and then I typed the following:

```
python3
>> import smart_settings
```

Then, I receive this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sanamanesh/Downloads/spotiboi-master/pages/smart_settings.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pylast
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylast'
```

However, I have already installed pylast. And, to double check, I checked the installed packages by typing "pip3 list" into terminal once I cd into my application. Additionally, the correct version of pylast is a dependency in my requirements.txt file.

Additionally, I tried to work through this problem on chatGPT to see if I'm doing something wrong or if there is another solution, but despite everything I have done, I still get the same error.

Comment: Does https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ help?